# How to find the solution of a parameterized equation

Tags: equation-solving

can someone tell me a software to isolate x? or can you do it to me? 0<x<1

-a b e^(-a x^b) x^(b - 1) + 1/8 (-a b e^(-a x^b) x^(b - 1) (1 - e^(-c(1 - x)^b)) - b c e^(-c(-x + 1)^b - a x^b) (-x + 1)^(b - 1))=0

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2474074).

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it does not appear to be appropriate for this site. The statement of the problem is not properly. It is not about the Mathematica software, though this is a site about Mathematica. And shows no effort for a solution whatsoever.

Comment: This belongs on math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I have assumed that you mean `E` rather than `e`

```
eqn = {-a b E^(-a x^b) x^(b - 1) + 
     1/8 (-a b E^(-a x^b) x^(b - 1) (1 - E^(-c (1 - x)^b)) - 
        b c E^(-c (-x + 1)^b - a x^b) (-x + 1)^(b - 1)) == 0, 0 < x < 1};
```

Use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
(inst = FindInstance[eqn, {a, b, c, x}, Reals, 5, 
    RandomSeeding -> 1234]) // Column
```

[image]

```
eqn[[1]] /. inst // N[#, 15] &

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Or assign numeric values to parameters

```
param = {a -> -1, b -> 2, c -> 1};

sol = Solve[Simplify[eqn /. param], x, Reals]
```

[image]

In either case you can use [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to convert the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions to their approximate numeric values. For example,

```
sol // N

(* {{x -> 0.0446004}} *)
```

Comment: What I need is to isolate X such that x depends on the parameters a b and c. that is X(a,b,c)